# Prestashop: Removing for order a group of products

Tags: prestashop

I have a Prestashop 1.5. I need to put as unavailable for order all products from certain categories. I can do this in the backoffice, but there are a lots of products. I have tried this query in the database:

UPDATE `ps_product` SET available_for_order = 0 
WHERE id_category_default IN ( 31, 24, 26, 54 );

It doesn't work. The products are still available for orders. Can I do this without change manually each products in the backoffice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the `ps_product_shop` table as well:

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET available_for_order = 0 WHERE id_category_default IN ( 31, 24, 26, 54 );
```